# Was it another Fishing Tournament?

Tags: launch, range-safety, sounding-rocket

[@KimHolder's thorough answer to *What are the consequences for a person who violates a launch exclusion zone?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/14290/12102) mentioned a fishing tournament. [@PearsonArtPhoto's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/#comment37469_14290) about scheduling launches during fishing tournaments got me thinking about [yesterday's launch that was cancelled](http://www.thedenverchannel.com/news/national/east-coast-could-see-colorful-clouds-sunday-morning-thanks-to-nasa) due to some "boats in the area".

> NASA had hoped to launch the rocket early Saturday, but had to scrub the attempt because of boats in the area where the payload is expected to fall back to Earth.

It turns out [*there was a fishing tournament*](http://www.americanfishingcontests.com/contest/List.aspx?State=VA) in Virginia on Saturday, three in fact! One was in Newport News VA, offshore.

Coincidence??? (satire, humor)

(The other two were state-wide/fresh water so they don't count.)

[image]

---

[Tweet](https://twitter.com/NASA_Wallops/status/870924874382024704) from NASA Wallops ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZsy.png)):

> Launch at @NASA_Wallops scrubbed today because of boats in the impact area.  We will try again between 4:26 and 4:41 a.m., Sunday, June 4. 4:47 PM · Jun 3, 2017

Comment: What are the consequences for a government agency that dares to disturb a calm tranquility of a fishing tournament?

Comment: @horsh ...and for those *darn fish* who take the bait and run with it, ruining an otherwise peaceful morning!