# Top American rocket launch sites?

Tags: launch-site, statistics

Which American rocket launch sites had the most space launches?

Comment: How specific do you want? Pad, complex, facility?

Comment: Sites. Like those this list - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rocket_launch_sites - not sure if they are complex or facility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cape Canaveral Air Force Station (Florida)
- Kennedy Space Center (Florida)
- Vandenberg Air Force Base (California)

The three above are the most used rocket launch sites of America. You may want to define Cape Canaveral and KSC as one and the same (Cape Kennedy). They're followed by Wallops (Virginia), White Sands (New Mexico) and the Corn Ranch (Texas). If you include rocketplanes you could also include the Mojave Air and Spaceport in California.

Comment: There is no such place as Cape Kennedy since 1973. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28152/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble Whatever. We can also call it the Merritt Island Space Launch Area.

Comment: Thanks. Got some numbers?

Comment: @JoeJobs No, sorry. But they are really frequently used. Perhaps 3 orbital launches per month on average (6 if you define CCAFS and KSC as the same), or something.

Comment: have you checked the [What's up at Wallops app](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26246/12102)? they may not launch the larges rockets but for sounding rockets it might be worth checking.