# Is it legal to sail near a Falcon-9 landing at sea?

Tags: landing, law, observation

Is it legal to pilot a sailboat near any of the autonomous spaceport drone ships?

For example, is it possible to stay near "Of Course I Still Love You" during the first stage landing?

Comment: different but related: [Was it another Fishing Tournament?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21777/12102) (currently unanswered), and [Databases of “scrubbed” launch attempts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22253/12102) (also currently unanswered) and [What's up with the “What's Up at Wallops” app?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26246/12102)

Comment: and much more closely related: [What are the consequences for a person who violates a launch exclusion zone?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14282/12102) It's probably illegal to utter the phrase "drive a sailboat" ;-) [If I drive a car and ride a motorcycle, what do I do with a boat?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/127034/217285)

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for noticing the serious grammar error!

Comment: Does the landing barge set up in  international waters as defined by international commissions (as opposed to certain countries who unilaterally claim ownership X miles off-coastlines)?   It would be interesting to see  exactly what "Laws of the Sea"  actually apply here.    There's also the law of "Don't be a jackass" and the distinct possibility of a Darwin Award.

Comment: During the last decades of orbit launches from Florida, spent first stages splashed into the ocean without hitting a sailboat or motor ship. Exclusion zones seems to be respected.

Comment: Even if it legal, it is certainly dumb (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvim4rsNHkQ). The process isnt perfect yet.